# rqt_plot only showing 0

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I use rostopic echo to display the messages, the number fluctuates. While I rqt_plot to plot the data, those data are always zeros. The message type is correct and rqt_plot is indeed displaying the plot. I can see lines of different colours and correct coloured legends. Just the values are incorrect. Anyone got clue how this is happening?

I don't think the rqt_plot node is getting correct values from the topic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242383/rqt_plot-only-showing-0/) by [nickhuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23201/nickhuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2016-10-14**:
Could you please add the type of the message you are trying to visualize? Does it have a header? If not, `rqt_plot` is not able to infer the time (the x-axis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your Y-axis limits might be too large to reflect the small changes in your data.
Try zooming in on the graph.

---

Originally posted by [Reijin_ThunderKeg](https://answers.ros.org/users/28064/reijin_thunderkeg/) with karma: 16 on 2016-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0